# no matching function for call to QTreeView::setModel(modelClass (*)())'

Tags: qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I am new to QT.  I am trying to create a simple file system browser.  I have created a separate class for the model and the view class.  Here they are:

//modelClass.h

```
#ifndef MODELCLASS_H
#define MODELCLASS_H
#include <QFileSystemModel>

class modelClass: public QFileSystemModel{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    modelClass();  //constructor
    QFileSystemModel* createModel(); //creates the QFileSystemModel
//public slots:
private:
};

#endif // MODELCLASS_H
```

//modelClass.cpp

```
#include "modelClass.h"

modelClass::modelClass(){
    createModel();  //calls to function below
}

QFileSystemModel* modelClass::createModel(){
    QFileSystemModel* model = new QFileSystemModel;
    model->setRootPath("/");
    return model;
}
```

//systemBrowser.cpp

```
#include "modelClass.h"
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    modelClass model();

    QTreeView tree;
    tree.setModel(&model);
    tree.setSortingEnabled(true);
    tree.header()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
    tree.resize(640, 480);
    tree.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Upon trying to compile this, I get the error:

```
    no matching function for call to 'QTreeView::setModel(modelClass(*)())'
    candidates are: virtual void QTreeView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel*)*
```

Could anyone please help me with this error?  I'm sure its just something simple I am missing.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Possibly reviving a corpse, I know. But still, this is easy:

The line

`modelClass model();`

is wrong. Your compiler assumes that this is an forward declaration of a function *model()* returning the type *modelClass*. Hence the error in the call to *QTreeView::setModel*

The line should be written as:

`modelClass model;`

Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse